# How can I add a geom_point layer using a different dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to add a fifth geochemical dataset to my graph that has a different scale from the previous four.  I have been successful in adding a second x-axis scaled to the additional dataset, yet I am having trouble plotting the dataset.

The first dataset is "data.fe.clean", and my second dataset is "data.fe3".  Here is my code:

```
p.fe.clean <- ggplot(data.fe.clean, aes(x=geochem.value, y=depth)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=geochem.type)) +
  geom_path(aes(color=geochem.type)) +
  facet_wrap(~ core) +
  scale_x_continuous(data.fe3, sec.axis = dup_axis(~.*0.05, name = "Fe (III) [nA]")) +
  geom_point(data.fe3, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x=geochem.value/0.05, y=depth)) +
  geom_path(aes(color=geochem.type)) +
  theme_bw() 
  
print(p.fe.clean)
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
`mapping` must be created by `aes()`
Backtrace:
 1. ggplot2::geom_point(...)
 2. ggplot2::layer(...)
 3. ggplot2:::validate_mapping(mapping)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
>
```

This also adds the most peculiar list of values beneath my figure, shown below:
[image]

How may I remove the list of values, while also plotting from the dataframe "data.fe3"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `data` argument is not the first argument in `geom_point()`, `mapping` is (you can see this in the help page; `data` is the second argument).  Given this, you are currently passing the dataset to `mapping`, which leads to the message/issue.  As the answer below states, write out the argument name explicitly to bypass issues of argument order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The `ggplot2` package uses to have issues with different geoms when using multiple sources of data. So if you use another geom, try to add `data=...`. Here the code, in lack of data for reproducible on issues:

```
p.fe.clean <- ggplot(data.fe.clean, aes(x=geochem.value, y=depth)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=geochem.type)) +
  geom_path(aes(color=geochem.type)) +
  facet_wrap(~ core) +
  scale_x_continuous(data.fe3, sec.axis = dup_axis(~.*0.05, name = "Fe (III) [nA]")) +
  geom_point(data=data.fe3, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x=geochem.value/0.05, y=depth)) +
  geom_path(aes(color=geochem.type)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Some code to connect the dots:

```
#Code 2 connect dots
ggplot(data.fe.clean, aes(x=geochem.value, y=depth)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=geochem.type)) +
  geom_path(aes(color=geochem.type)) +
  facet_wrap(~ core) +
  scale_x_continuous(data.fe3, sec.axis = dup_axis(~.*0.05, name = "Fe (III) [nA]")) +
  geom_point(data=data.fe3, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x=geochem.value/0.05,
                                                     y=depth,color=geochem.type)) +
  geom_path(data=data.fe3,aes(x=geochem.value/0.05,
                              y=depth,color=geochem.type)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

The issue that you had other values in axis is because you duplicated data in `scale_x_continuous()`. Here the code:

```
#Code 3 clean up other labels in axis
ggplot(data.fe.clean, aes(x=geochem.value, y=depth)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=geochem.type)) +
  geom_path(aes(color=geochem.type)) +
  facet_wrap(~ core) +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(~.*0.05, name = "Fe (III) [nA]")) +
  geom_point(data=data.fe3, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x=geochem.value/0.05,
                                                     y=depth,color=geochem.type)) +
  geom_path(data=data.fe3,aes(x=geochem.value/0.05,
                              y=depth,color=geochem.type)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Duck, that worked well to get the points on the figure.  However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get `geom_path()` or `geom_line()` to actually connect those dots.  Again, I'm happy to provide the `dput()` if necessary, it's just obnoxiously long.

Comment: Thank you so much @Duck.  This was a humongous help, and I really appreciate your time!  The graph looks great.